# Python: How can I perform addition operator for two different text files?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, addition

I want to perform addition operation for two files, for file A, to read the values line by line in order to add values from file B. How to enable read file line by line for file A? Given file A and B as belows:

**A.txt**

```
2.0 1.0 0.5
1.5 0.5 1.0
```

**B.txt**

```
1.0 1.0 2.0
```

**Expected output in new file**

```
3.0 2.0 2.5
2.5 1.5 3.0
```

**Example code**

```
import numpy as np

with open("a.txt")as g:
    p=g.read().splitlines()
    p=np.array([map(float, line.split()) for line in p])

with open("b.txt")as f:
    x=f.read().splitlines()
    for line in f:
        x=np.array([map(float, line.split()) for line in x])

XP=x+p       
print XP
```

I'm still improving the code. Is there any other alternatives for doing so?

Comment: Does file B.txt always have only one line?

Comment: For this example, yes.

Comment: And what is your question? Is your code not working? Do you want it to be more efficient?

Comment: Why are you using `numpy`?

Comment: @Xiong89 what do you mean, "for this example"? Do you need code that works with exactly one line in B.txt or multiple lines in B.txt?

Comment: @timgeb exactly one line.

Comment: A better approach: 1. read `b.txt` into a list. Iterate over `a.txt` and print/store the added data during the iteration. There is no need to store the entire data and then ask `numpy` to add them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from operator import add

b = []

with open("B.txt") as b_file:
    aux = b_file.readline()
    b   = [float(i) for i in aux.split()]

with open("A.txt") as a_file:
    output = open("output.txt", "a")
    for line in a_file:
        aux = [float(i) for i in line.split()]
        res = map(add, aux, b)
        output.write(str(res) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `np.loadtxt`, for example:

```
In [11]: import numpy as np
In [12]: A = np.loadtxt('path/to/A.txt')
In [13]: B = np.loadtxt('path/to/B.txt')
In [14]: A + B
Out[14]: array([[ 3. ,  2. ,  2.5], [ 2.5,  1.5,  3. ]])
```

Saving the result to a txt file is equally simple:

```
In [15]: np.savetxt('path/to/C.txt', A+B)
```